# Issues processing based on execution of batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I may be doing this wrong. Here is what i am trying to do:

1. Opening up a batch file (labelled: run office install.bat) iv'e created.
2. Call an install batch file (labelled: install.bat) and set an error report against it (currently using a different batch file to the one normally use, as
   it installs office 2013 so just copied and renamed another bat to
   the same for testing). I know this batch file works on its own and
   with GOTO:EOF and EXIT /B it should output an error code of 0 or >1
3. Based on the error code returned display an error message stating
   the install failed or display a message showing the install was a
   success and delete the install package.

Here is the code:

**run office install.bat**

```
    CD "C:\source\Microsoft_Office_2013_01"
    CALL install.bat 2> InstallCommand.err

    FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('InstallCommand.err') DO set size=%%~zA
    IF NOT "%size%"=="0" (
        ECHO Error installing MS Office 2013. Please check the log files.
        TYPE InstallCommand.err
        GOTO:EOF
    )


IF "%size%"=="0" (
    ECHO MS Office 2013 installed, now deleting install folders...
    TYPE InstallCommand.err
    RMDIR /s /q "C:\source\Microsoft_Office_2013_01" 2> delCmd.err
        OR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('delCmd.err') DO set size=%%~zA
        if not "%size%"=="0" (
                ECHO Error deleting install folders
                    TYPE delCmd.err
                    )
                IF "%size%"=="0" (
                    ECHO install folders deleted successfully
                    TYPE delCmd.err
                        )
        )

PAUSE
EXIT
```

**install.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
:delete

ECHO Deleting OffScrub10.vbs 
CD c:\temp
DEL /f /q c:\temp\OffScrub10.vbs 2> delCmd.err

FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('delCmd.err') DO set size=%%~zA
IF NOT "%size%"=="0" (
    ECHO Error deleting OffScrub10.vbs
    TYPE delCmd.err
    GOTO :EOF 
)


IF "%size%"=="0" (
    ECHO OffScrub10.vbs deleted successfully
    TYPE delCmd.err
)

PAUSE
EXIT /B
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should at a minimum tell people what it is doing, and what you expect/want it to do.  Also, the roughly middle line of the first batch file should be `FOR` not `OR`.

Comment: Sorry typo should be FOR. i did give a description of what i want it to do at the top however will add in some comments to the Bat file.

Comment: It's not so much what you want it to do that's missing, as what it _does_ do... E.g. does it die immediately? Does it run the installer but not detect whether it worked or not? What output/error messages do you get?

Comment: Sorry i have figured out what was wrong, initially due to the CD c:\temp it saves the err file in the wrong location so the main script is looking for it there, stating its not found to do the size check on. 
That issue is now resolved however it now keeps the .err file open in the directory it goes on to try and delete (C:\source\Microsoft_Office_2013_01)  so cant complete. if i test with another bat hopefully it will be fit for purpose as the install bat that will be used  wont have the deletion check.

Comment: thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a modified version of your two files. I have tried to keep them similar to those you've posted such that you can still follow them:

**run office install.bat**

```bat
@ECHO OFF
IF /I NOT "%__CD__%"=="C:\source\Microsoft_Office_2013_01\" (
    PUSHD "C:\source\Microsoft_Office_2013_01" 2>NUL||EXIT/B)

CALL "install.bat" 1>NUL 2>"%TEMP%\InstallCommand.err"

FOR %%A IN ("%TEMP%\InstallCommand.err") DO SET "size=%%~zA"

IF %size% NEQ 0 (
    ECHO= Error installing MS Office 2013. Please check the log files.
    TYPE "%TEMP%\InstallCommand.err"
) ELSE (
    ECHO= MS Office 2013 installed, now deleting install folders...
    PUSHD "%TEMP%"
    RD /S /Q "C:\source\Microsoft_Office_2013_01" 1>NUL 2>"delCmd.err"

    FOR %%A IN ("delCmd.err") DO SET "size=%%~zA"

    IF %size% NEQ 0 (ECHO= Error deleting install folders
        TYPE "delCmd.err") ELSE (ECHO= install folders deleted successfully)
)

TIMEOUT -1
EXIT /B
```

**install.bat**

```bat
@ECHO OFF
IF /I NOT "%__CD__%"=="C:\temp\" (PUSHD "C:\temp" 2>NUL||EXIT/B) ELSE (SET "_=T")

ECHO= Deleting OffScrub10.vbs 
DEL /A /F "OffScrub10.vbs" 1>NUL 2>"%TEMP%\delCmd.err"

FOR %%A IN ("%TEMP%\delCmd.err") DO SET "size=%%~zA"

IF %size% NEQ 0 (ECHO= Error deleting OffScrub10.vbs
    TYPE "%TEMP%\delCmd.err") ELSE (ECHO= OffScrub10.vbs deleted successfully)

TIMEOUT -1
IF NOT DEFINED _ POPD
EXIT /B
```

*You need to also be aware that `run office install.bat` cannot be running from `C:\source\Microsoft_Office_2013_01` otherwise you will be trying to delete it whilst it is still running*